Custom icon marker in cartopy map
Is there any way to import a custom image/icon in python to use as a marker for a point (based on latitude/longitude) instead of the standard markers such as "o", '^", etc.?
For example, I am plotting hospitals in the map using the plot_points function in cartopy, and I want to use a hospital icon ("H") image that is similar to the one available in ArcGIS attached.
.
Is possible to pass the image into the shapes parameter of the plot_points function?
Any help would be appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
